# Suggestion for displaying elements randomly within a container div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for a demo that randomly position elements within a container div and fade them out/in at random times. Any suggestions? Maybe there is a premade library that has the function built in? Thanks a ton.

Comment: not exactly what you described but still cool (and open source) is: https://popmotion.io/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function generateRandomNode(container) {
  var node = document.createElement('SPAN');
  node.style.top = Math.random() * 100 + '%';
  node.style.left = Math.random() * 100 + '%';
  container.appendChild(node);
  setTimeout(function(){node.remove();},1000);
}
setInterval(function() {
  generateRandomNode(document.getElementById('container'));
},1);
```

```css
#container {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
.random-element {
  position: relative;
}
.random-element>* {
  width:3px;
  height: 3px;
  opacity:0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: fade 500ms ease;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {opacity:0}
  50%{opacity:1}
  100%{opacity:0}
}
```

```html
<div class="random-element" id="container"></div>
```